# Feature file in cucumber is not coming with green color even though all the necessary plugins are installed

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, bdd

i am using eclipse 
and i have already installed Natural 0.7.6 and cucumber eclipse plugin but still my feature files are not coming with green icon.

Comment: Can you add some kind of screenshot? Also does the feature file or runner execute correctly?

Comment: @Grasshopper This is how feature file look like, keywords are not recognized. although have installed natural and cucumber eclipse plugin from the update site "feature files - https://www.dropbox.com/s/77ui2wm4etfepfd/feature_file_.png?dl=0" on running the feature file it is generating the code template but on inserting the selenium code it is either not executing the code or throwing error. please suggest what needs to be fixed

Comment: Add the runner code and also the error which is more inportant. Regarding the feature file try with a tab indent.  Though if cucumber generates correct template code it is working fine.

Comment: @Grasshopper Thanks it is working now

Answer (score 0):

If you have just installed the eclipse plugin for cucumber and the feature file steps are not colored then here is the simple solution.

I assume, you have already checked the following:

- Plugin Installed correctly
- The extension of this file is correct.

**Solution:** What went wrong is that you accidentally opened the file with a 'Text Editor'. All you need to do is change the default to "Editor"

1. Right-click on Feature file.
2. Go to **Open With** and select **cucumber editor**